# Tooltip remains on page when changing views from rowClick

Tags: anychart

I am having issues with AnyGantt library. I have set the following eventListener:

```
  chart.listen(anychart.enums.EventType.ROW_CLICK, function(event) {
                var programID = event['item'].get('id');
                $state.go(..);
            });
```

And it does work - it redirects me to the webpage I want. However, there is an issue that really bothers me - there is a tooltip, that has not been deleted - it is added to the bottom of my html style, and I cannot find a way to get rid of it. Any help is more than appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the troubles you are experiencing, please contact us via [support@anychart.com](http://support@anychart.com) with a detailed description of the issue so we can assist you. We will be glad to help you!

Answer (score 0):

in the latest versions of anychart you can do tooltip().hide();
https://api.anychart.com/latest/anychart.core.ui.Tooltip#hide